# What is the difference between these methods and which way properly checks for NULL?

Tags: php, null

All three methods are a check for null,

```
if($sth == NULL)

if($sth === NULL)

if(is_null($sth))
```

which way is the proper one?

Comment: I guess the second one would be the fastest one, but that's what I guess, I haven't done any benchmark.

Answer (score 11):

They check three different things:

```
if ($sth == NULL)
```

This checks if `$sth` is loosely equal to `null`.  This means that this would pass if `$sth` was actually `0`.

```
if ($sth === NULL)
```

This checks if `$sth` is exactly equal to `null`.

```
if (is_null($sth))
```

This checks if the *type* of `$sth` is the null type (the others test the *value* of `$sth`).

The `===` and `is_null` techniques will always give the same answer; `==` will sometimes give a different answer.

Comment: I don't think `is_null` is the quickest way, because of the function overhead. Not that the speed difference will matter much though. +1.

Comment: @Shef To my surprise (I thought I'd done this before with a different result) you're right. Edited.

Comment: What the difference between two first? I see absolutely equals statements

Comment: @silev `null == 0` is true, because of [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The first only tests if the `$sth` is equal to NULL which 0 will also be true.
The second checks if the type is equal too. So only `NULL` as value for `$sth` will be true.
The third will only work on variables and not on function results.

Also a little tip: From time to time it happens to me that I mistype `if($sth == NULL)` to `if($sth = NULL)` which will result in hard to find errors. Better type `if(NULL == $sth)` where you will get an interpreter error when you write it wrong that will point you to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use

```
if(is_null($sth))
```

but I think either is good